# Implicit model binding in laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel-5.1

Implicit model binding in laravel 5.1 described very poor. When I am trying to do like in manual I always get error   `ReflectionException in RouteDependencyResolverTrait.php line 81: Class App\Http\Controllers\App\News does not exist`
Of course it is namespace issue, but I cannot understand to fix it. I tried to comment `$namespace`, but it is not helped me.

```
<?php namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Routing\Router;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';

    public function boot(Router $router)
    {
        parent::boot($router);
        $router->model('newsitem', 'App\News');
    }
```

here is the error description

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
1/1 ReflectionException in RouteDependencyResolverTrait.php line 81: Class App\Http\Controllers\App\News does not exist

    in RouteDependencyResolverTrait.php line 81
    at ReflectionParameter->getClass() in RouteDependencyResolverTrait.php line 81
    at ControllerDispatcher->transformDependency(object(ReflectionParameter), array('newsitem' => object(News)), array('newsitem' => object(News))) in RouteDependencyResolverTrait.php line 61
    at ControllerDispatcher->resolveMethodDependencies(array('newsitem' => object(News)), object(ReflectionMethod)) in RouteDependencyResolverTrait.php line 44
    at ControllerDispatcher->resolveClassMethodDependencies(array('newsitem' => object(News)), object(NewsController), 'getItem') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 162
    at ControllerDispatcher->call(object(NewsController), object(Route), 'getItem') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 112
    at ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
    at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 114
    at ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(object(NewsController), object(Route), object(Request), 'getItem') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 69
    at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(Request), 'App\Http\Controllers\NewsController', 'getItem') in Route.php line 203
    at Route->runWithCustomDispatcher(object(Request)) in Route.php line 134
    at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 708
    at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
    at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 710
    at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 675
    at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 635
    at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 236
    at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 50
    at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
    at call_user_func_array(array(object(VerifyCsrfToken), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
    at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
    at call_user_func_array(array(object(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 62
    at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
    at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
    at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
    at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
    at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
    at call_user_func_array(array(object(EncryptCookies), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
    at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
    at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
    at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 122
    at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 87
    at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

Answer (score 0):

To me this looks wrong:

`App\Http\Controllers\App\News`

unless you have a subdirectory in App\Http\Controllers called `App`.

**If** you do have an `App` directory in your Controllers directory, make sure that your route file(s) have the correct name spacing

```
Route::group([
        'namespace'  => 'App',
    ], function () {

        // News resourceful controller
        Route::resource('/','NewsController');
});
```

If this still doesn't help, can you post an example of your controller?

Answer (score 0):

this is working solution

RouteServiceProvider.php

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Routing\Router;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Route;
use App\News;

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';

    public function boot(Router $router)
    {
        parent::boot($router);

        Route::bind('newsitem', function($item) {
            return News::whereSef($item)->firstOrFail();
        });

    }
```

routes.php

```
Route::get('news/{newsitem}', ['as' => 'news.item', 'uses' => 'NewsController@getItem']);
```

NewsController.php

```
public function getItem($newsitem)
{
    dd($newsitem);
}
```